# Why is the 3D plot of $ \vec{r}=\big{\langle} \pm 2 \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{9}}, v, u + 3v \big{\rangle} $ shown as a surface and not a curve?

Tags: maple

I have a plane $$z=x+3y$$ and an elliptical cylinder $$\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9}=1$$ and I want to plot their intersection.

I have $$x = \pm 2 \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{9}}$$ and a parametric equation

$$ \vec{r}=\big{\langle} \pm 2 \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{9}}, v, u + 3v \big{\rangle} $$

If I plot this in maple I get a surface, but I am expecting a curve:

```
plot3d([[-2*sqrt(1 - v^2/9), v, u + 3*v], [2*sqrt(1 - v^2/9), v, u + 3*v]], u = 0 .. 4, v = -3 .. 3)
```

[image: plot of intersection of plane and elliptical cylinder]

I don't see why this shape has any vertical (z-dimension) length.

Comment: `u = 0..4` What is $u$ here?

Comment: u is a mistake from me, I forgot to substitute the value of u there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have two parameters, i.e. $u$ and $v$, you should expect a surface ($n$ parameters $\Rightarrow$ $n$ dimensions). So the problem is your formula – you shouldn't introduce $u$ at all. What you do with $x$ and $y$ is good, but then you should get
$$
z = x+3y = \pm 2\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{9}} + 3v.
$$